# Need help for user form delete function

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am able to have the data deleted in my first sheet but it does not work the same for sheet 5. I am not hitting any error. How can i fix this?

```
'Delete Function'
  Private Sub Delete_Click()
    Row = 3
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim StaffID As String
    lastrow = Sheets("Staff Details").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   StaffID = TextBox6.Text
   For Row = 3 To lastrow
   answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you wish to delete the Staff Record?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Delete Staff Record")
   If answer = vbYes And Cells(Row, 1).Text = StaffID Then
    Cells(Row, 1).EntireRow.Delete

   ElseIf Cells(Row, 1).Text = StaffID Then
    Sheet5.Activate
    Cells(Row, 1).EntireRow.Delete

   End If
      Next Row
      TextBox6.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Comment: What error you are encountering with ,, since I'm guessing error in this Row,,,` TextBox6.SetFocus` Bcozz `Textbox` doesn't supports this it should  'TextBox6.Select, !!

Comment: You need to modify this `Sheets("Staff Details")`, before you RUM Macro ,,, `Sheet Name`,,!!

Answer (score 0):

**This Macro will help you to Delete Records from any Sheet if finds the ID in Column A, written in INPUT BOX.**

```
Sub DeleteAllRow()
Dim strTodel As String
Dim colTofind As String
Dim delRows As Long
strTodel = InputBox("Enter the ID")
Do While True
 On Error GoTo Err_handle
 Range("A:A").Find(What:=strTodel, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, After:=ActiveCell).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
 delRows = delRows + 1
Loop
Err_handle:
 MsgBox "Number of Delete Rows - " & delRows
 Exit Sub
End Sub
```

**How it works:**

- Copy & Paste this Code as Standard Module while Click the `This Workbook Icon in VBA Project Explorer Windows`.
- Using this as `Workbook's Macro` will help you to delete records from any of the Sheets.
- `Range("A:A")` is editable, you can set any Column to search the ID to delete records.